# Zendesk - Custom field change event not working

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app, zendesk-sdk

I am working on Zendesk server side App, There is a `orderno` custom filed in ticket form.
what i want to achieve is, get value of `orderno`  when its value got changed.

Previously, I have achieve something similar as following.

```
if (client) {
   client.on('ticket.requester.name.changed', function(e) {
      console.log("e === > ", e);
   });
}
```

Zendesk has some event [docs here.](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/integration-services/trigger-events/ticket-events/#custom-field-changed) I tried but not succeed.

Please guide me how i can get custom filed value when it changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you are referring to is for ZIS, a different set of tools for handling integrations. ZAF events for ticket sidebar location are stated [here](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/apps/apps-support-api/ticket_sidebar/#events).

This snippet listens for field 123123 change in a ticket_sidebar app:

```
client.on('ticket.custom_field_123123.changed', function(e) {
  handleChange();
});
```